# Speed differences between SQL Server 2012 and PostGIS UnionAggregate

Tags: postgis

There seems to be a massive difference in speed between PostGIS and SQL Server 2012 with a union aggregate function.

```
SELECT geometry::UnionAggregate(the_geom)
FROM loc
GROUP BY LocalityCo
```

vs

```
SELECT ST_Multi(ST_Union(the_geom))
FROM dummydata.loc 
GROUP BY "LocalityCo"
```

I get less then a second in SQL Server 2012 but around 25 seconds in PostGIS.

PostGIS version is: `1.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1`

Is there anything I can do to speed up the PostGIS query or it's just the way it is?

Note: Both have spatial indexes.

Comment: related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/is-there-a-dissolve-function-in-postgis-other-than-st-union

Comment: What setup is both the SQL Server 2012 and PostGIS 2.0 on?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably upgrade your postgis version to 2.0.1 including the latest dependancy libraries (geos 3.3,...) then test it again.

Comment: Yeah I did this and got about 15 seconds

Comment: That's a pretty simple query, so it's just the way it is. Would you share your data for profiling and improvement? You could add and enhancement ticket to trac.osgeo.org/postgis and attach the data (is it points, lines, or polygons?) or a link to it, that would be great.

Comment: I'll find out if I can share the data.  If I can I'll create a ticket for it.